# I need help on how to stop this batch-file from closing when an illegal character is entered by the user

Tags: batch-file, cmd, error-handling

I'm pretty much a novice and need help on how to stop this batch-file from closing when any illegal character is entered by the user...

For example, when a users input is ";" or "&&" and the input basically crashes the batch-file.

My Code:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
taskkill /f /im process1.exe
taskkill /f /im process2.exe
taskkill /f /im process3.exe
taskkill /f /im process4.exe
taskkill /f /im process5.exe
:restart
set choice=
set /p choice="Do you want to run these batch commands again? Type 'y' and press 'Enter' to re-execute the batch commands again or type 'n' and press 'Enter' to terminate: "
if not '%choice%'=='n' if not '%choice%'=='y' goto restart
if '%choice%'=='n' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='y' goto start
:end
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Use choice.exe instead](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)

Comment: Choose choice instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I  stop this batch-file from closing when any illegal character is entered?

**Option 1**:

Write your `if` expressions using `"` instead of backticks:

```
if not "%choice%"=="n" if not "%choice%"=="y" goto restart
if "%choice%"=="n" set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if "%choice%"=="y" goto start
```

**Option 2 (better)**:

Use `choice`:

```
choice /c yn /m "Do you want to run these batch commands again? Press [y] or [n]
if errorlevel 2 goto :exit
if errorlevel 1 goto :restart
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) - Accept user input to a batch file. Choice allows single key-presses to be captured from the keyboard.

Comment: Both of your options helped me out immensely, thank you!

Comment: Let me suggest to add the `/I` option to `if` for the comparison to become case-insensitive...